# Maximum Explode variable

Tags: php, explode

I Want to explode custom numbers of variables. 
My php code is here

```
$date="23-05-2015";

$var = "$var1, $var2, $var3";

// I want get $var value in list($var) = what I want{ list($var1, $var2, $var3)}

list($var) = explode('-', $date, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$var` variable is weird, it keeps a list of comma-separated names of other variables....
Why would you do that ?

You have 2 options:
Either you use the [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) on the variable names:

```
$date="23-05-2015";
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode('-', $date, 3);
```

Or you do the [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) hack, and keep the $var variable as is:

```
$date="23-05-2015";
$var = "$var1,$var2,$var3";
extract(array_combine(explode(',',$var,3),explode('-', $date, 3)))
```

Obviously, I think option #1 is the way to go